# Set version and build for Flutter app in Codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, versioning, codemagic

I have trouble setting up Flutter project on Codemagic (for ios) to get version from `pubspec.yaml` `version` field (which is set with build number - `0.7.0+10`. I tried substituting `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` with `$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)` and `$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)` but on codemagic I get error:

```
{
    "message": "Exception caught.",
    "userInfo": {
        "NSLocalizedDescription": "Exception caught.",
        "NSLocalizedFailureReason": "*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil"
    },
    "code": -1010
}
```

and I can see in logs that Version and Version code are empty:

```
Supported platforms: iPhoneOS
Version code: ""
Version: ""
```

I tried putting variables in quotes based on other stackoverflow answer:

```
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>"$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)"</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>"$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)"</string>
```

I tried without them, tried curly braces, nothing seems to work. Is there any other setting that might override this either in Flutter or Codemagic? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with my info.plist values being same as yours:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Manually setting the version number and code in pubspec.yaml works without a fuss.

Are you running `flutter build ios ....` as your build script or something else? If you are building with xcode commands without running `flutter build ios`, before xcode scripts, then this might be the issue as flutter fills the information in xcode files when using their commands.